# Check if user is logged in multiple choice

Tags: php, authentication

I want check if user is logged in. I have two login system. First is Facebook login system and second is my own created login system. I want to ask if user is login with Facebook system OR my own login system. I have tried code like this. Before or operator is Facebook login and after or is my own login system. Both works separately but not in same system.
Facebook login system works but my own login system not works if use `if (!isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] ==false)`

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'] ==false) || (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
    echo "Please, log in!";
    header('Location:login_page.php');
}
```

Comment: Your code is essentially `if (facebook) || (my_login) {}`. Can you do that without parentheses wrapping the whole thing like `if ((facebook) || (my_login)) {}`? **EDIT:** I just tried it and got a Parse Error.

Comment: Tryed. There was no Parse Error anymore, but code doesent work. `(my_login)` system not log in. Facebook login system works.

Comment: Keep in mind, you cannot use `header()` after outputting text. Perhaps this is your problem? If you are not seeing `"Please, log in!"` and the facebook system works and you fixed the boolean logic, by process of elimination there must be a problem with the `$user->is_logged_in()` function.

Comment: I will check that. But like I said `(!$user->is_logged_in())` works if I use only that choise

Comment: The problem is that I have to be logged in with Facebook before `(!$user->is_logged_in())` works. Any solutions?

Comment: Edit your question rather than posting a comment. It is too hard to figure out what you are asking when the question is disjointed. Also, what you are saying now makes it sound like you saying they have to be logged in with Facebook AND your own system which is different than what you said before.

Answer (score 2):

you can add two session in each login system. Also you can check the login system

for example if user logined by facebook

add a session and set it

```
$_SESSION["loginedby"]="facebook";
```

your login system

```
$_SESSION["loginedby"]="default";
```

and you can check if user loginned by facebook  redirect another page

```
if($_SESSION["loginedby"]=="facebook";)
echo 'you logined by facebook !';
elseif($_SESSION["loginedby"]=="default";)
echo 'you logined by default login system !';
```

Comment: if i understood this right. Ahmet solution works if user is already logged in. My point was that I want let users log in with Facebook login system or my own login system. After that users have permission to see content of page.

Comment: you can create a table or set a new colum in your setting table could be the colum name is  permission if  permission =1 you can set a session["permition"]==1 that main is user have  permission lo login